# how to debug ClassLoader not finding a file in Java

Tags: java, classloader, javahelp

I'm trying to integrate JavaHelp system inside my project developped using Eclipse.
I have the following code extracted from an [example](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javahelp/):

```
private HelpSet getHelpSet(String helpsetfile) {
        HelpSet hs = null;
        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        
        try {
            URL hsURL = HelpSet.findHelpSet(cl, helpsetfile);
            
            hs = new HelpSet(null, hsURL);
        } catch(Exception ee) {
            System.out.println("HelpSet: "+ee.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HelpSet: "+ helpsetfile + " not found");
        }
        return hs;
    }


HelpSet hs = getHelpSet("doc/Sample.hs.txt");
```

HelpSet file cannot be found, but exist (doc/Sample.hs.txt). I suppose there is something wrong with path, or ClassLoader usage, but I can't figure out what is the problem.
Does anyone have an idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: @h3xStream : thanks. I tryed. But getProperty return multiple path separated by ";". Which do I have to consider?

Comment: I taught one path could be missing.. If you can see the folder including the docs, the problem isn't there.

Comment: (Previously remove comment) You can verify the effective classpath : `System.getProperties().getProperty("java.class.path", null);`

Comment: the path where are the docs is returned correctly by getProperty. Anyway seems that findHelpSet can't locate the file

Answer (score 2):

```
hs = new HelpSet(null, hsURL);
```

The HelpSet-Class gets `null` instead of the ClassLoader instance, so it can't load anything. This should be:

```
hs = new HelpSet(cl, hsURL);
```

Comment: that's not it. The code execution don't reach that line. I changed it anyway thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's the path you're looking in. You should double check it.

Answer (score 1):

The .hs.txt extension will not work. Try giving your helpset just the .hs extension.